# How to filter objects with JsonServiceClient

Tags: servicestack

```
//DTO
public class SampleDto : IReturn<SampleDto>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class ListSampleDto : IReturn<List<SampleDto>>
{
}
//Service
public class SampleService : Service
{
  public object Get(ListSampleDto request)
  {
    List<SampleDto> res = new List<SampleDto>();
    res.Add(new SampleDto() { Id = 1, Description = "first" });
    res.Add(new SampleDto() { Id = 2, Description = "second" });
    res.Add(new SampleDto() { Id = 3, Description = "third" });
    return res;
  }
}
//Client
string ListeningOn = ServiceStack.Configuration.ConfigUtils.GetAppSetting("ListeningOn");
JsonServiceClient jsc = new JsonServiceClient(ListeningOn);
// How to tell the service only to deliver the objects where Description inludes the letter "i"
List<SampleDto> ks = jsc.Get(new ListSampleDto());
```

I don't know how to sent the filter criteria (e.g. get only the objects where Description inludes the letter "i") from the JsonServiceClient to the service.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, you typically expand your input Dto (in this case the `ListSampleDto`) with properties that you evaluate server-side to provide the proper response:

```
// Request Dto:
public class ListSampleDto
{
  public string Filter { get; set; }
}
...
// Service implementation:
public object Get(ListSampleDto request)
{
  List<SampleDto> res = new List<SampleDto>();
  res.Add(new SampleDto() { Id = 1, Description = "first" });
  res.Add(new SampleDto() { Id = 2, Description = "second" });
  res.Add(new SampleDto() { Id = 3, Description = "third" });
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Filter)) {
    res = res.Where(r => r.Description.StartsWith(request.Filter)).ToList()
  }
  return res;
}
...
// Client call:
List<SampleDto> ks = jsc.Get(new ListSampleDto { Filter = "i" });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I missed (sorry for the long easter delay)